# Why can't a UIDeferredMenuElement be added to an array of UIAction, whereas you can form an array with one?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton, uiaction

Say you have<sup>†</sup>

```
var ele = // an [UIAction]
```

So,

```
yourButton.menu = UIMenu(children: ele)
```

Every app needs to know when the menu opens, so you use the usual trick,

```
let trick = UIDeferredMenuElement.uncached({completion in
    print("menu opened")
    completion([])
})
```

However! If you try doing this:

```
ele.append(trick)
```

It does not work!!

```
[X] Cannot convert value of type 'UIDeferredMenuElement' to expected argument type 'UIAction'
```

However! It's fine to do this! ->

```
aButton.menu = UIMenu(children: [ele[0], ele[1], ele[2], trick])
```

this for example will also work

```
aButton.menu = UIMenu(children: ele + [trick])
```

but this does *not* work

```
ele.append(contentsOf: [trick])
```

Note too that `ele.append(trick as! UIAction)` does not work, `unrelated type`.

What is the explanation for this arcane mystery?

---

† for completeness, I usually make items something like this idiom ...

```
let noms = [
    ("TAG", "Do crazy things", "arrowtriangle.right.and.line.vertical.and.arrowtriangle.left"),
    ("BLAH", "Even more\nwild stuff.", "rectangle.grid.3x2"),
    ("LOUT", "Logout now", "lock.open")
]

let ele = noms.map({ fn in
    return UIAction(title: fn.1, image: UIImage(systemName: fn.2)) { [weak self] _ in
        guard let self else { return }
        aButtonProcess(fn.0)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is that `children` is explicitly typed as an array of a *superclass*, UIMenuElement, from which both UIMenu and UIAction inherit.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenuelement

If you type `ele` explicitly as an array of UIMenuElement you can do the same.

```
var ele : [UIMenuElement] = [myAction]
// now append your deferred menu element
```

Whereas, if you form the array with both from the start, Swift *infers* the superclass as the array element type.

In other words, if Cat is an Animal and Dog is an Animal, you cannot append a dog to an array of Cat, but an array with a dog and a cat is an array of Animal and you can append another animal to it.